# React get data from state

Tags: reactjs

I have this function:

```
addEntry = e => {
    this.setState({[e.target.id]: [...this.state.[e.target.id], 'New Entry']}, () => {console.log(this.state)})
};
```

I want to concat data in the state but I don't know how to reach it since I use this for multiple `input` with different `id` each.

I know `this.state.[e.target.id]` will not work but I'm just showing what I need which is to get to state data that have the same name as the `input` `id`

Here is the state:

```
id: 14
product_campaign: "none"
product_category: "Shoes"
product_colors: ["white"]
product_created_at: "2019-03-19T10:40:42.712909Z"
product_description: "A Tshirt"
product_gender: "MEN"
product_images: ["/media/Screenshot%20(49)_dSkvMsA.png"]
product_materials: ["Cotton"]
product_name: "Tshirt"
product_price: 12.99
product_size: ["S"]
product_sku: "M-Shoes-jtfnd57p"
```

Comment: What is the full structure of the state?

Comment: @jsdeveloper I added state

Comment: error here `this.state.[e.target.id]` should be `this.state[e.target.id]`

Comment: how are you calling addEntry ? and how are you setting the id in the rendering ?

Comment: @Alexandr it worked thank you.

Comment: @SimpleWebDesigner do you mind marking it as correct answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

error here `this.state.[e.target.id]` should be `this.state[e.target.id]`